# Receiving an empty body in retrofit Response

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to get data from http URL.
My Interface Class :

```
public interface SlotsAPI {

    /*Retrofit get annotation with our URL
      And our method that will return a Json Object
    */
    @GET(url)
    retrofit.Call<JSONObject> getSlots();
}
```

My request method.

```
public void getResponse(){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

    //Creating an object of our api interface
    SlotsAPI api = retrofit.create(SlotsAPI.class);
    retrofit.Call<JSONObject> callback = api.getSlots();
    callback.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<JSONObject> response) {
        if (response != null) {
            Log.d("OnResponse", response.body().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    });
}
```

In the response I am receiving an empty body.And the server responds with 200 OK.

```
D/OnResponse: {}
```

But when I open the URL in browser I am getting JSONObject on the screen.

Comment: Can u provide the URL?

Comment: Sorry, i can't.But it's a regular http link.

Comment: I suggest you use a tool such as Fiddler or Charles and proxy both traffic through them. You can then compare the differences in the requests and get an idea.
Maybe it's because of the UserAgent string.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you should try like this way ....

```
public interface SlotsAPI {

/*Retrofit get annotation with our URL
  And our method that will return a Json Object
*/
@GET(url)
Call<JsonElement> getSlots();
}
```

in request method

```
 retrofit.Call<JsonElement> callback = api.getSlots();
callback.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<JsonElement> response) {
    if (response != null) {
        Log.d("OnResponse", response.body().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @curiousMind. I was stuck here for a long time.

Comment: @user1035292 happy coding :)

Answer (score 7):

Please check your JsonObject. If you want to get response in json you must be define a response type JsonObject not JSONObject other wise specify the pojo class in your interface.

Comment: Their spelling is close `JsonObject` and `JSONObject`. We should note that one is `com.google.gson.JsonObject` which used by `gson` convertor factory and other one is ` org.json.JSONObject` which we must use first one i.e. `com.google.gson.JsonObject`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not understanding the retrofit filosofy.
The correct interface should be:

```
public interface SlotsAPI {

    /*Retrofit get annotation with our URL
      And our method that will return a Json Object
    */
    @GET(url)
    JSONObject getSlots();
}
```

When you call the getSlots method, retrofit will automatically do the HTTP request and return the JSONObject.
You will need to do this out of the main thread.

Comment: I think that call will not be asynchronous. But in my case i need to call the server asynchronously.So i am using callback methods.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the url of @Get is relative path

- @Base URL: always ends with /
- @Url: DO NOT start with /

Example:

```
  String URL = http://api.co/base/ ;
```

And

```
  @GET("webservice/syncdown")
  JSONObject getSlots();
```

You may receiving a list of Slots. the Gson converter will handle it if you sending array of json

```
 @GET(url)
 retrofit.Call<List<Slot>> getSlots();
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know if this works.Thanks.

Comment: No, it's still giving the same empty body.

Comment: I have a question, are you sure from the type of the object that you retrive you are setting a converter factory GsonConverterFactory and the response body is also JSONObject ?


See my update to understand my question

Answer (score 0):

You are using the retrofit 2 or 1? The version 2 still is in beta.
If you are using the version 1. Use this:

```
public interface SlotsAPI {

    /*Retrofit get annotation with our URL
      And our method that will return a Json Object
    */
    @GET(url)
    void getSlots(Callback<JsonElement> callback);
}
```

With this the call will be asynchronous.

Comment: I am using Retrofit 2.I know that 2 is in Beta. So are you sure it's something wrong with 2.0 or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, and [answer from curiousMind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997008/receiving-an-empty-body-in-retrofit-response/36007320#36007320) saved my day.
More on the same subject: if you need to get a value from a pair use:

```
String value = response.body().getAsJsonObject().get("pair_name").getAsString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call<Void> getSlots() worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void APIRetrofit_method() {
      Retrofit  retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RecyclerInterface.JSONURL)
               // .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RecyclerInterface api = retrofit.create(RecyclerInterface.class);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = api.getString(); /// GET METHOD without passing params
        // Post METHOD CODE START
//        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
//        params.put("name", "yuva");
//        params.put("pass", "" + "123");
     //   Call<ResponseBody> call1 = api.getProspectList(params);
        // Post METHOD CODE END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                   try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "GetProspectlistresponse" + "" + response.isSuccessful());
                        utility.hideProgressDialog();
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                            String remoteResponse = new String(response.body().string());
                            Log.d(TAG, "Holidaylistresponse" + "" + remoteResponse);
                            try {

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(remoteResponse);
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("Holidays_Details");

            if (array.toString().equals("[]")) {
                holiday_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holiday_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String holidayDate = c.getString(TAG_HOLIDAYDATE);
                    String holidayName = c.getString(TAG_HOLIDAYName);
                    String holidaytype = c.getString(TAG_HOLIDAYtype);

                    HashMap<String, String> customers = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    customers.put(TAG_HOLIDAYDATE, holidayDate);
                    customers.put(TAG_HOLIDAYName, holidayName);
                    customers.put(TAG_HOLIDAYtype, holidaytype);
                    arrayList.add(customers);
                }

                getHolidaylistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            utility.hideProgressDialog();
    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("ErrorResponsestring", call.toString());
            }
        });
    }
String JSONURL = "https://demonuts.com/Demonuts/JsonTest/Tennis/";
    @GET("json_parsing.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> getString();
//    @POST("getProspectList")
//    @FormUrlEncoded
//    Call<ResponseBody> getProspectList(@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> body);
 implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0'
```